# Jenkins GitHub Plugin Build Queue

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm using the Jenkins GitHub plugin to build when a change is pushed to GitHub. This option is working pretty well. However if I make multiple pushes while one build is running the next build will combine a bunch of commits into one build.

Is there a way to build every commit that gets pushed to GitHub individually? If you have a ton of commits in one build that can make it a lot harder to find where the problem happened and how to fix it.

Comment: AFAIK the Github webhook pushes out to Jenkins and Jenkins prepares the next build with the most recent commit and there's no way to change it. I suspect it's because you're supposed to wait to see if the build was successful before you make another commit as you have no idea if it will build successfully, assuming you're using Jenkins to automate your testing etc.

Comment: @Harmelodic When builds can take a pretty long time it seems unreasonable to wait for the build to finish to commit. So there no good workarounds or ways to fix this? Just something you have to deal with?